# Error when deploying my UWP app but I don't want to deploy to a phone

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

The error is:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error      Error : DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during >bootstrapping stage 'Connecting to the device '30F105C9-681E-420b-A277->7C086EAD8A4E'.': 
>   DeviceException - Windows Phone IP over USB Transport (IpOverUsbSvc) is not >running. Retry after starting Windows Phone IP over USB Transport >(IpOverUsbSvc) from the services management console.   FamilyNotes

But I'm not trying to deploy to a phone. I just want to run the application in windows

I downloaded an example app called [FamilyNotes](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/06/21/familynotes-introducing-a-windows-uwp-sample-using-ink-speech-and-face-recognition/#b2ThKMmx4AKm8LI9.97). It's an example of the MS Cognitive Services. I go to debug it and get the above error.

As per the links in the blog post, I've installed the emulator and changed some config settings in the bios but can't get it running.

I'm totally new to this UWP thing. My experience is web .NET MVC.

Comment: Are you running ARM Version? Change it to X86 or X64.

Comment: Could you build that sample without any changed any config settings?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the register files , [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/74fafd96-50cf-4d77-9d7a-41620c5487a5/uwpsdkipoverusbsvc-service-missing-in-windows-10-rc-build-10240?forum=wpdevelop) msdn link describes the solution for the exact problem you are facing .

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have configured it to run on your local machine? 
[image: this is how your toolbar should look like]

If the last part is the arrow and "device" it tries to deploy to another device, like a phone. Also check if you have the right processor architecture in the second box